# How to pass a bloc to another screen using go_router on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc, flutter-go-router

On Flutter I would like to pass a local `bloc` to another screen.
This is how I used to pass a bloc to a new route when using the default navigator.

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(
        builder: (BuildContext context) =>  BlocProvider.value(
          value: localBloc,
          child: MyPage(),
      ),
    ));
```

But now, I'm using the **`go_router`** package for navigation. How can I provide the local `bloc` to the screen I want using **`BlocProvider.value()`**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go\_router pass an object/bloc to new route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74581819/go-router-pass-an-object-bloc-to-new-route)

Comment: Not really as I won't be able to access it as context.read<LocalBloc>() from the other page

Comment: To use context.read, you need to have blocprovider in your widget tree. In the answer I shared, it's passing bloc to the page via constructor on go router. To use context.read, you need to wrap your page with blocprovider on router(in exact same place). Same as your code example.

Comment: The problem is the bloc might not be available inside the router file as it is a local (not global) bloc, so it's defined inside some page.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly. You have a bloc in some page, you want to access from other page via context.read. For context.read, you need to have bloc provider. So when you define your route, wrap it with blocprovider.value and pass the bloc. You need to use blocprovider.value and pass the same instance that you get from router's state.extra in the other question. What exactly is the problem in that flow? If you pass to router's extra param, you can grab it on router.

Comment: The problem is when I define the route, the bloc isn't accessible as it's not a global bloc but a local one. Like say I've a Cart Page and a Checkout Page. Now a Cart Bloc is defined in Cart Page(so local bloc). When I navigate to Checkout Page, I want to be able to pass that Cart Bloc as BlocProvider.value(). But that isn't possible. I know it seems like it's very possible, but it isn't. If you think it is, give me a reproducible code.

Comment: I understand that it's not a global bloc. That's why you need to pass via router. My reproducible code is exact same as this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74856689/9779791

What exactly is wrong with this code piece? You are using blocprovider.value when you are defining your routes. value param for blocprovider is coming from router's state. Which is state.extra! as YourBlocClass.
Once your page is wrapped with BlocProvider.value, you should be able to access using BlocProvider.of(context) or context.read()

Comment: the issue is that it is not working

Answer (score 7):

You need to **pass the bloc** to the `route` using `BlocProvider.value`.

```
context.goNamed('/', extra: HomeBloc());

GoRoute(
  path: '/',
  builder: (context, state) { 
    return BlocProvider.value(
      value: state.extra! as HomeBloc,
      child: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
),
```

And then inside `HomeScreen` you can get bloc using.

```
final bloc = context.read<HomeBloc>();
```

Answer (score -2):

##### BlocProviders  are `lazy` loaded by default.

> It automatically handles closing the instance when used with Create. By default, Create is called only when the instance is accessed. To override this behavior, set lazy to false.

Therfore instead of passing `bloc` between routes,The best practice is to:

Provide all the `BlocProvider` in the `main.dart` using the `MultiBlocProvider`

And add it before `App()` so that all the child can get access to it .

```
  runApp(
      MultiBlocProvider(
          providers: [
            BlocProvider<BlocA>(
              create: (context) => BlocA(),
            ),
             BlocProvider<BlocB>(
              lazy: false                   // if you want the bloc to be loaded here.
              create: (context) => BlocB(),
            ),

          ],
          child: App()
      )
  );
```

And access it using `BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context).add([BlocAEvent]);` in your desired screen

Comment: What if I wanted the bloc to only be initialized when I am at a certain screen, for example when at search screen. Then wanted to pass the bloc to a search detail screen

Comment: `flutter_bloc` takes care of that for you, by loading the `bloc` only when initialized. I have edited my answer . Please follow up

Comment: Lets say I've a screen that I want the state of it to be initialized each time I open that screen, if the bloc was associated with that screen, upon each routing to that screen the bloc will be created with the initial state. But if I defined it globally, the state will persist even when I re-enter the screen.

Comment: create a function `randomFunction()` in bloc and call it while initializing the bloc, and then every time you open the desired screen, run `BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context).randomFunction()`

Comment: Yeah, you see this would've been automatic if the bloc was associated with the screen. And I think this was why such an option was given in the first place

Comment: You can use get_it, injectable for that case too, just decorate them as @singleton. I'm using for general purpose ones like purchasebloc, authbloc etc. ButI was(probably OP too) looking a way to initiate new bloc everytime you open the page. Let's say chat page.