# Go_router pass an object/bloc to new route

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-routes, flutter-go-router, gorouter

I use to pass a BLoC instance to a new route like so :

```dart
Navigator.of(context).push<void(FavoriteDetailPage.route(_favoriteBloc));
```

```dart
class FavoriteDetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const FavoriteDetailPage({super.key});
  

  static Route route(FavoriteBloc favoriteBloc) {

    return MaterialPageRoute<void>(
      settings: const RouteSettings(name: 'favorite_detail'),
      builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(
        value: favoriteBloc,
        child: FavoriteDetailPage(),
      ),
    );
  }

 ...

}
```

I'm in the process of migrating my app routing to [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) & can't find how to the same. -> Provide the same bloc instance to a new route, as go_router `parameters` can only be `String`

I could provide the BLoC above my `MaterialApp` to make it available to my all app but I don't want to provide it to my all app *(just to those two sub routes)*

Answer (score 1):

##### Use `extra` parameter in `context.goNamed()`

```
 GoRoute(
        path: '/sample',
        name: 'sample',
        builder: (context, state) {
         FavoriteBloc favoriteBloc = state.extra as FavoriteBloc ; // -> casting is important
          return FavoriteDetailPage(favoriteBloc : favoriteBloc );
        },
      ),
```

Receive it as :

```
class FavoriteDetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  FavoriteBloc favoriteBloc;
  const FavoriteDetailPage({super.key,required this.favoriteBloc});
 }
```

Comment: it only works if bloc has toJson/fromJson. JsonUnsupportedObjectError (Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'ChatBloc')